# How to add horizontal line to a pandas df plot?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, time-series

I want to draw a line on y=0. However, I am not sure how to do that using pandas built-in charting.
`df.mean(axis=1).plot()` I am running this and that is the result.

[image: Time series plot]

Comment: [`axhline`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch the `ax` instance returned by `plot`, and you can use `axhline`:

```
ax = df.mean(axis=1).plot()
ax.axhline(0, c='r')
```

Output:

[image]